# python join dataframes on Time

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes in python where df1 contains minute data over a month, and df2 contains a weighting of minute data (two columns: 'Time' and 'Weights' for 1 day only. They share a Time column with dtype returning "object" looks like "08:00:00". Here the # of rows of df1 is much longer than df2. I attempt to join using:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Time', how='left')
```

But data returns NaN for the 'Weights' column. Any idea why?

Edit:

df1 comes from sql, df2 comes from CSV file:

https://ufile.io/e7fc5

https://ufile.io/0d37c

```
df1['DateTime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df1['Time'] = df1['DateTime'].dt.time
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'], errors = 'coerce')
df1=df1.set_index('timestamp').between_time('08:00','17:00').reset_index()

col_names = ['Time', 'weight']
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/abc/weights.csv", names = col_names)
```

df1
timestamp          datetime64[ns]
DateTime           datetime64[ns]
Time                       object
dtype: object

df2
Time       object
weight    float64
dtype: object

I did this and returned TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'str'. Looks like I have two types of objects?

```
print bool(df1.Time[5]- df2.Time[5])
```

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: Agreed about adding your code. I would also test equality between e.g. `df1.Time[i]==df2.Time[j]` where `i` and `j` are values that appear to be equal, to make absolutely sure that you're dealing with equal objects.

Comment: and it would help if you also showed your data.